# How should I pass data between WPF Windows involving `MainWindow` (C#)?

Tags: c#, wpf, window

I am currently starting a C# project in which I am modelling a simple ATM machine, and will therefore need several screens. I have run into the problem of passing data between screens before when I was coding a StockTicker board game adaption, but I don't think my method of solving it was very good.

A lot of my problems stem from the fact that I use `MainWindow` as the primary window of the application. I am able to easily pass data from the secondary window back to the primary window, as I am able to access the properties of the `Window1` class after it has been closed. However, to tranfer from `MainWindow` to `Window2`, I have to add a parameter to the constructor of `Window2` that will enable me to pass in the necessary values.

While this does work for a small application, it is my opinion that this would get very long/messy for the more things that need to be passed to `Window2`. In addition, I do not know at all how to access any of the methods that I declare on `MainWindow` from `Window2`. Since `MainWindow` is the primary screen, most of my coding is in its class.

- How can I access a method that I have put in `MainWindow` from `Window2` ??

(For clarification) I have spent some time looking around, and cannot find a clear example that specifically involves `MainWindow`, and needing to access variables/methods found in it.

---

Here is my C# code (I have tried to have clear variable names). The gist of the program is that you can have some data stored on Form 1, which then is passed to Form 2 when the button is clicked. From here, it can be modified however the user wishes, and then it can be accessed again from Form 1 when Form 2 is closed.

In this example, I am merely showing that I have found a way to transfer data from form to form, but I am sure that there is a better way. Specifically, I am sure that there is a nicer way than having to possibly code different constructors with varying paramaters for the `Window2` class.

---

First WPF Window Code:

```
namespace Banking_System
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnSwitchForm_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string strForm1Text = txtForm1TextBox.Text;

            Window2 newWindow = new Window2(strForm1Text);
            newWindow.ShowDialog();

            txtForm2TextBox.Text = newWindow.strForm2Text;
        }
    }
}
```

Second WPF Window Code:

```
namespace Banking_System
{
    public partial class Window2 : Window
    {
        public string strForm2Text { get; set; }

        public Window2(string form1)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            txtForm1.Text = form1;
        }

        private void btnSwitchBack_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            strForm2Text = txtForm2TextBox.Text;
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Would I be better off to create another WPF window, and have it load as soon as the `MainWindow` loaded, and then hide `MainWindow` and "pretend" that the other window was the primary screen? Because then I could simply access the properties in the same manner that I do above (when transferring from `Window2` to `MainWindow`).

ie. When needing to access a variable/method from another window, simply declare a new temporary window and access the properties/methods of it:

```
FakeMainWindow wndPrimary = new FakeMainWindow();
wndPrimary.strProperty= "test";
wndPrimary.methodCall();
```

The primary attraction of this way for me is that I can access methods on another window (as illustrated above), which I cannot do while using `MainWindow` as my primary form.

**Summary**

- How can I access a method that I have put in `MainWindow` from `Window2`?
- Is it better to create another WPF window, and pretend that it is my "primary screen" so that I can easily access its properties?
- If not, is there a better way of working with `MainWindow`?

If I'm missing anything, let me know. Thanks!

Comment: *MvvmLight* Messages, *Prism* event aggregator, decoupled messages for the win

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can actually access your application's main window without passing any references between windows. `Application.Current.MainWindow` returns the instance of the main window that is declared in app.xaml. It returns a `Window` (which your main window derives from) so you will need to cast it in order to access its members.

For example, you could use this code in your second window:

```
((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).txtForm1TextBox.Text = "Some text";
```

---

Having said that, I kindly suggest that you do some research into WPF design patterns (specifically [MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel)).

Comment: 5 years after the fact...I am marking this as the accepted answer due to the prompt to research MVVM and related design patterns

Answer (score 2):

Pass the whole window
this will be MainWindow

```
Window2 newWindow = new Window2(this);
```

Comment: Thanks, it does work. Is this a recommended/safe method though? It seems so simple, but I haven't found it anywhere before.

Comment: If it works and it is not safe then take it up with Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the First window as the Second window's DataContext :

```
 namespace Banking_System
 {       
     public partial class MainWindow : Window
     {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();           
        }

        private void btnSwitchForm_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {               
            Window2 newWindow = new Window2(strForm1Text);
            newWindow.DataContext = this;
            newWindow.ShowDialog();      
        }            
  }

 public partial class MainWindow2 : Window
 {
      public MainWindow2()
      {
         var window1 = this.DataContext;
      }
 }
```

}

Additionally i would recommend that your Window would have it's own ViewModel set as it's DataContext which you can send to the other window. 
In this way you can also bind properties directly to both windows and not worry about updating them manually .

Answer (score 0):

Create a static class, and put static methods or static properties that are common to all windows.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to send data from the parent to the child at any time. ChildFormVariable.SomeVariable....

Every control in a form is public, it just has to have a set name to access it.

However I don't know how to send data from the child to the parent at any time. I know how to send only via the constructor of the child or when closing.

So since we can only communicate one-way,that is, the parent giving and taking data form the child, here is what you do:

in the child form's code create a public bool variable DataChanged. Then create a button that when clicked will set that bool to true.

Now in the parent form create a check that will check every 10 millisecond the child form's DataChanged, and if true, then make the parent form access the child form's other controls or variables to extract data from. If controls, I recommend that they have a name.