# How to pass a value from Page in Window 2 to Page in Window 1 WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have 2 Windows (Window 1 and Window 2). While on Window 2, I hide Window 1 using ShowDialog.

From Window 1(Page A) I click a button that takes me to Window 2(Page B). An operation occurs on Window 2(Page B) and I have to pass the processed answer back to Window 1(Page A).

I have a variable called ProcessedAnswer at the top of Window 1(Page A), as soon as the compiler runs on from ShowDialog, I call the value ProcessedAnswer.

Is there a way to pass this value between pages on different windows without creating a new instance of the pages?

Comment: There should be a main viewmodel. The viewmodels of Window 1 and WIndow 2 should be properties of that main viewmodel, and the page viewmodels should be properties of Window 1 and Window 2 respectively. The main viewmodel should be responsible for managing this relationship: One common way would be for ProcessedAnswer to be part of yet another child viewmodel, and both of the pages would be given references to a shared instance of that child viewmodel. You could also give PageB an event which is raised when the operation completes. MainViewModel would add a handler to that event when...

Comment: ...the while viewmodel tree is created, and the handler would assign  `this.Win1ViewModel.PageA.ProcessedAnswer = this.Win2ViewModel.PageB.ProcessedAnswer;`. A lot of people would recommend using the existing `PropertyChanged` event instead of adding a new event. That's not a bad idea either. In your case, it sounds like Win1's viewmodel may have direct contact with Win2's viewmodel. In that case, Win1 could add the handler to that event and leave the main viewmodel out of it.

Comment: please refer to following post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30063550/how-should-i-pass-data-between-wpf-windows-involving-mainwindow-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By MVVM design patter, I suggest you use a ViewModel in Windows 1 and pass it through Windows 2. like following:

Windows1.cs

```cs
ViewModel2 vm2 = new ViewModel2();
...
windows2.DataContext = vm2;
if(windows2.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    ProcessedAnswer = vm2.something;
}
```

Windows2.cs

```cs
(DataContext as ViewModel2).something = somevalue;//here you can modify the passing value and pass it when ShowDialog finish
```