# Passing data between two opened windows

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, .net-4.8

I'm doing my own project manager with some extra options that I have in mind.
I stuck on Project categories (when you create project, you will have to choose it)

I want it to look like that:
When you click (...) button, "Choose a category" window opens

[image]

In the "Choose a category" window there are some buttons. When you click on one of them it highlights and string called "category" gets the value of the button`s name (button that we clicked). I want to send that string to the first window and display it in the Category text box (when we click on "choose" button.

[image]

Can someone help me?
How can I send that string to the first window? 
It may be very easy but I have some trouble and I can`t find the solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I pass data between WPF Windows involving \`MainWindow\` (C#)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30063550/how-should-i-pass-data-between-wpf-windows-involving-mainwindow-c)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your are using MVVM pattern or not, but in any case you may use a "Messaging" library:

Example: **MVVM Light Messenger**
You may find details here [MVVM Light Messenger](http://dotnetpattern.com/mvvm-light-messenger)

The basic usage would be

```
public class ViewModelA : ViewModelBase
{
    public void SearchCommandMethod()
    {
        MessengerInstance.Send<NotificationMessage>(new NotificationMessage("notification message"));
    }
}

public class ViewModelB : ViewModelBase
{
    public EmployeeListViewModel()
    {
        MessengerInstance.Register<NotificationMessage>(this, NotifyMe);
    }

    public void NotifyMe(NotificationMessage notificationMessage)
    {
        string notification = notificationMessage.Notification;
        //do your work
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please keep in mind that this is just a rudimental example. It's always good to check the data the user choosed or not. And this is not the only solution for your question. In my opinion it's more important for you to understand the underlying system and what it means to transport data between windows, before you just simply copy solutions from here.

This is a really simple example, how you can pass data between windows : it's just a public property with private setter. After the user clicks on the button to choose a category, the property gets set and the window gets closed.

```
private void BtnCategory_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
            CategoryWindow categoryWindow = new CategoryWindow();
            categoryWindow.ShowDialog();

            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(categoryWindow.CategoryTitle))
            {
                // category is empty or not set
            }
            else
            {
                // category is set and not empty
            }
}
```

```
public partial class CategoryWindow : Window
{

        public string CategoryTitle { get; private set; }

        public CategoryWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void BtnChoose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CategoryTitle = GetSelectedCategory();

            this.Close();
        }

        private string GetSelectedCategory()
        {
            return string.Empty; // Return the selected Category here... string.Empty is just a placeholder!
        }
    }
```

If both windows have to stay opened, maybe events are the right thing for you. An event is firing when the user chooses a category. Other windows can subscribe for this events to get informed.

```
private void BtnCategory_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CategoryWindow categoryWindow = new CategoryWindow();
            categoryWindow.OnCategoryChanged += CategoryChanged;

            categoryWindow.Show();
        }
        private void CategoryChanged(object sender, CategoryChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Category))
            {
                // category is empty or not set
            }
            else
            {
                // category is set and not empty
            }
        }
```

```
public partial class CategoryWindow : Window
    {
        public EventHandler<CategoryChangedEventArgs> OnCategoryChanged;

        public CategoryWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void BtnChoose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var selectedCategory = GetSelectedCategory();
            OnCategoryChanged?.Invoke(this, new CategoryChangedEventArgs(selectedCategory));
        }

        private string GetSelectedCategory()
        {
            return string.Empty; // Return the selected Category here... string.Empty is just a placeholder!
        }
    }

    public class CategoryChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public string Category { get; private set; }

        public CategoryChangedEventArgs(string category)
        {
            Category = category;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Oh, Thank you very much! Now I understand my problem. You helped me a lot! It works just as I wanted